# Automating production deployments for asp.net applications

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy

I am trying to figure out a better approach for the production deployment of our asp.net MVC applications. At present we deploy the application using the "Publish" feature in visual studio. I have listed our current process below.

1-> Open the latest code in Visual studio.
2-> Right click on the web project and Publish it to a folder using the "release" configuration.
3-> Copy the contents of this folder to the production machine.

I am not sure if this is the right approach. Are there any better alternatives available? I cannot use deployment tools such as "Octopus deploy" as my organization doesn't want to spend money on them.

does anyone have any recommendation for a better process?

Thanks
Suneeth

Answer (score 0):

Octopus deploy brings a lot of control and visibility to the deployment chain. It also handles the hub and spoke model with its Server and agents.

So, to do it manually, I would go for:

1. Powershell to Deploy
2. A Windows service, to handle the deployment payload

I do this mechanism, as a fall back strategy to Octopus Deploy.

Hope that helps.